# E0401:Unable to import 'django.db'

Tags: django, virtualenv

So i'm studying python crashcourse  and after finishing the basics I jumped to the django project.

I created a virtual env, installed django and created an app with manage.py startapp command.

I use Visual Studio Code, and the problem is when I go to models.py it gives an error that it's unable to find django.db module

[unable to import error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhqMf.png)

Now I understand this is because of the file structure, which is as per my research the correct one, and I followed the book carefully, however i don't know how to fix this and I feel that i'm missing something.

This is my file structure for the virtual environment

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQ17j.png)

Any idea how to fix it ? :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thank you Incognos !

To be more specific The solution was :

enter "code ." in the terminal and then a new VS opens.
Ctrl+Shift+P -> Select Interpreter
select the environment that starts with ./env or .\env
run Ctrl+Shift+` to activate it

Comment: help me a lot Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. VSCode was by default using the wrong python for this project and therefore did not see the installed dependencies.

Answer (score 10):

VS is not seeing your virtualenv. You need to activate it for VS code so that it knows that django is installed in the virtualenv see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Answer (score 4):

it happens because pylint is installed outside your virtual environment. So install pylint inside virtual environment with this command (pip install pylint).

Answer (score 2):

Note: If you're using Visual Studio Code - Insiders you'll use `code-insiders .` instead of the `code .` command.

Then, a new window will open and you can set your virtual environment interpreter there.

Reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6627

Answer (score 1):

in my case, the problem was solved by opening VS-Code in the directory where virtualenv is located.

Answer (score 0):

Click Ctrl-shift-p to access the Command pallete, then search for Python: Select Interpreter. Click on it and then select on the one that has been recommended by the editor.